# What is a .do file? What is the MIME type for it?

Tags: asp.net, struts, mime-types

I never heard of a .do file. I had a request from some one saying that their link is not working. It is a example.do file all other files on that folder are opening except the .do files.

How can I fix it? Is it MIME type or Some thing else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be related to Struts. Check the following [link](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/works.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link. It helped me understand what a .do file is.

Comment: The link is broken.  Can you provide more information in the post?